# WSO2 Governance Registry 4.5.3 Web app mode

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Can any one tell me how to run wso2 governance registry 4.5.3 in web app mode rather running it in stand alone mode ? I have successfully built the source code and I want to know exactly how I can run in web app mode so that I can debug it in the eclipse ??

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to debug the source code all you have to do is start the WSO2 Governance registry with debug enabled when starting the server this can be done by starting the server with the following command.

sh wso2server.sh debug 8000

And you can remotely debug the server through an IDE like eclipse or Idea with port 8000 or some other port number you wish to use.

EDIT: Regarding running WSO2 governance registry in web app mode take a look at this blog post which explains how WSO2 carbon can be run as a web app might help you

[1]http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.com/2012/09/running-wso2-carbon-as-web-app-apache.html

Comment: Can you tell me how to configure the project into the Developer studio ?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to setup debug configurations in your IDE which is can be learn using this [wso2 article](http://wso2.com/library/225/)

Then start the BPS server script with debug option as follows.

```
<bps_home>/bin/wso2server.sh -debug 5005
```

After you start the server you will get this message:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Then start debugging from your IDE!

[image]

This is the debug configuration I used:

[image: edit configurations]